# Can't start a Kawasaki GPX 750

Tags: motorcycle, starting, fuel-system, carburetor, kawasaki

I'm in the process of getting my 1986 Kawasaki GPX 750 back in running condition. The bike was sitting in the garage for two years. In this period it wasn't started even once. Two years ago the engine ran perfectly and I haven't tuned anything since then.

**What I did:**

1. Replaced all 4 sparkplugs with news ones
2. Replaced the battery with a new one
3. Cleaned the air filter

**What are the symptoms**

1. Can't start the engine if the choke is not fully on. When I start the engine the revs jump to 2000 rpm and engine stops
2. Can't make the engine run more then a minute
3. If I try to turn the gas bar engine also stops.
4. After I try starting bike for some time gas starts leaking trough gas drain hose

What may be the issue ?

Comment: Any luck getting this thing running good?

Answer (score 6):

**Your carbs are clogged with varnish and bad gas**

The remnants of gas that has evaporated are a gummy hard varnish inside of your carburetors.  You have a bit of work to do.

You need to ***completely*** disassemble the carburetors and thoroughly clean all of the nooks, crannies, jets, fuel galley's and air galley's in order to get your bike back in working order.

The entire bank of 4 carbs requires removal and cleaning.  You can dunk the entire set in a 'bath' of solvent to eat away the dried up gas or 'varnish' and to soften it up.  Afterword you will need to take carb cleaner and 'blow out' all of the fuel galley's.  Additionally you will need to unplug your jets with a small wire and/or compressed air.

This varnish is preventing fuel from getting into your motor.  You will need to clean the entire fuel system, especially the gas tank.  You may have some rust in your gas tank as well.  The petcock is probably clogged and may need a rebuild kit for it to replace the plastic screen.  You will need to determine that upon disassembly.

Here are some similar questions and answers that may assist you in your endeavor.

Here is a carburetor removal process on a similar bike. It applies to yours.

- **[How do you get the carburetors out of a 1983 Kawasaki KZ1000 P?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/244/how-do-you-get-the-carburetors-out-of-a-1983-kawasaki-kz1000-p)**

Here is the process to clean a set of carbs with bad gas in them.

- **[Aprillia Pegaso 650 won't start after cleaning carbs, what might be wrong?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/aprillia-pegaso-650-wont-start-after-cleaning-carbs-what-might-be-wrong/26327#26327)**

As you are troubleshooting the carbs after you clean them, you may need to identify issues to get the bike to where it is.  Here is a post related to troubleshooting rich and lean conditions with your carburetor set.

- **[Symptoms of Lean or Rich carb settings on a motorcycle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/732/symptoms-of-lean-or-rich-carb-settings-on-a-motorcycle/23937#23937)**

After you are all done and the bike is running somewhat normal, you will need to balance your carburetors as the final step.

- **[Motorcycle Four Body Carburetor Synchronization Balancing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/motorcycle-four-body-carburetor-synchronization-balancing/24312#24312)**

If you have any further questions about the issues you are experience please ask follow ups!  Best of luck to you, you'll get it running again.  Keep the battery on a trickle charger as you are troubleshooting so you don't take it all the way down as you are attempting to get it running.

Comment: "carbs requires removal and cleaning" you forgot dis-assembly...

Comment: @Moab  Thank you!   Crucial step.   I added it in.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your carb(s) are plugged and need cleaned. If the fuel in the carbs has ethanol in it, the carbs are going to be caked with crap. The floats could be ruined. There are a lot of things going on. Getting the carbs rebuilt or at the *very least* cleaned up, is going to be a must. All of the symptoms you saying are pointing to carb issues.